# whether "throws UncheckedException" makes any sense

Tags: java, exception, checked, unchecked, throws

I was studying the `Exception` chapter in java and wondering if it does any good to put some `throws UncheckedException` after a method signature. I can see that with checked exceptions that kind of a statement is necessary to compile the code and with *try, catch* and *finally* all exceptions can be handled. But my question is what difference if at all does it make to add a `throws UncheckedException` after a method signature?
for example, to compile the following code with a `File` object, you need to have a checked exception:

```
void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    File f=new File("c:\\java\\xyz.txt");
}
```

But what effect such a statement has in the following code:

```
public static int method1(String str)throws NumberFormatException{
    int i=Integer.parseInt(str);
    return i;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `throws` clause with an `UncheckedException` is only for documentation purposes, it has no functional effect.
However, this definitely makes sense in certain situations. The usual reason to do this is if you expect someone else to use your class, and you want to make it clear that your method might throw a certain `Exception`.

Comment: It is generally a better idea to use javadoc for documentation (@throws)

Answer (score 0):

writing `throws` means the function well not handle the exception, but well give you the honor.